# What is the rewrite rule to change www.domain.com to www.domain.com/es/?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To add www at the beginning
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# To add / at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

# Add /es/ at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/es/ [R=301,L]

# Friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/$ /?services=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/services/([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1&services=$2 [L]

# ErrorDocument 404 /web/page-404.php
# ErrorDocument 500 /web/page-500.php
```

I'm trying and trying but I can't get to automatically adding "/es/" when www.mydomain.com is typed.

For now, the "# Add /es/ at the end" block is adding "/es/?lang=es".

Some help? Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not that block that is adding the `?lang=es` That is the block below.

Comment: I need the block below to redirect www.mydomain.com/?lang=es to www.mydomain.com/es/. Also, if I use my "Add /es/ at the end" rule and comment that block below nothing happens. How could I get both? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no. This rule definitely adds a `lang=es` query parameter: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]`

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But I need both: www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/es/ and www.mydomain.com/?lang=es to www.mydomain.com/es/. My question is... which are the correct rewrite rules, since these ones are not working?

Comment: One more attempt: The rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]` explicitly adds the `lang=...` query parameter. Yet here in the question you ask why that happens. Answer: you do it. Why do you have that rule? It does _not_ rewrite from `www.mydomain.com/?lang=es` to `www.mydomain.com/es/`. I have the impression you did not really understand how such rules work. I suggest you take a look at the documentation... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I'll try again: if I were able to find a solution reading the documentation, I wouldn't be asking this. No, I don't really understand this, but I'm trying to, that's why I'm asking. I've been fighting with this for 2 days and no getting a solution, my question is not about laziness or whim. Please, if someone has a solution, I'll be forever grateful, but telling me what is already happening doesn't help.

Comment: By the way, please read my question: "which are the correct rewrite rules, since these ones are not working?"

Comment: OK, please believe me that I am not trying to annoy you or anything. I simply thought that it is fine if I simply mention that that rule actually rewrites to `.../es/?lang=es` in an absolute manner! Whilst you claim that is exactly what you do not want to happen. I added an answer below to enhance that point. It might well be that this is not the final solution for you, since I do not know what else you want to achieve by your rules. It is just meant to point out the issue at hand here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /es/ [R=301,L]
```

It redirects

```
example.com
```

to

```
example.com/es/
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments to the question these rules simply do not make sense in combination:

```
# Add /es/ at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/es/ [R=301,L]

# Friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
```

They do not make sense because what happens here is this: the first fule rewrites *any* incoming request to `...../es/`. Then the next rule rewrites that request again to `.../es/?lang=es`, since that second rules regular expression takes the `es` and appends is as query parameter `lang=es` which is exactly what you claim you do *not* want to happen.

So what is that second rule there for? Remove it!

It might well be that this is not the final solution for you, since I do not know what else you want to achieve by your rules. It is just meant to point out the issue at hand here...